# Writing contents of file to HTML page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, graphviz

I'm using graphviz to generate a client side imagemap, which generates both the image file and a text file containing the map HTML code. Is there anyway I can dynamically read this file and write this map information onto the HTML page when it loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a server side scripting language for this purpose.